# How to include configuration data from another Maven project?

Tags: maven

I have a multi repository Maven based project with some projects having multiple modules. There are `jetty-maven-plugin` configurations used in running jetty locally which reference database connection details in project-local `src/etc/jetty-plus.xml` files. They are used when running integration tests and when a developer runs the applications locally.

I'm trying to separate out database create & upgrade scripts and hopefully the jetty files to a separate Maven project and have the other projects declare dependencies on modules within this new project.

I was thinking of having to have a separate module for these files only and declare some sort of dependency on this that the maven jetty plugin could access. My main issue is how to configure the jetty plugin which currently has this config - I want to be able to pick up this file from a dependency - but this file is developer specific and is not part of the repository code.

```
<webAppConfig>
    <contextPath>/someService</contextPath>
    <jettyEnvXml>src/etc/jetty-plus.xml</jettyEnvXml>
</webAppConfig>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to put the jetty-plus.xml files into a separate maven project, then have the jetty plugin read the jetty-plus.xml file from this project?  Or, will each developer have his own jetty-plus.xml file somewhere on his machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven share configuration between multiple plugin executions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795922/maven-share-configuration-between-multiple-plugin-executions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the maven dependency pluginis what you need. It has an [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) goal that allows copying parts of other artifacts (e.g. your configuration data) to your project. Have a look at the [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) of the page.