# Maven share configuration between multiple plugin executions

Tags: maven

If I have multiple executions of a Maven plugin and they share at least one of the same configuration values, is there a way for me to share this configuration between all executions of the plugin.

Consider the trivial case of a build plugin with two executions:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- ID, version... -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ID1</id>
            <configuration>
                <myConfig>foo</myConfig>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>ID2</id>
            <configuration>
                <myConfig>foo</myConfig>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I rewrite this so that both the `ID1` and the `ID2` executions use the same value for the `myConfig` configuration?

Comment: Is this supposed to actually read <id>ID2</id> for the second <execution>? (if so then it will answer my question, which is not what you asked but shows how to get around the error I am getting when trying to build my jar with two executions in the same plugin :) )

Comment: tested it in my own code with same id and it throws a duplicate execution.id error. Edited this question to show that execution id's must be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not move common configuration outside concrete executions?

```
<plugin>
    <!-- ID, version... -->
    <configuration>
        <commonConfig>foo</commonConfig>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ID1</id>
            <configuration>
                <specificConfig>bar</specificConfig>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>ID1</id>
            <configuration>
                <specificConfig>baz</specificConfig>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works for some plugins I use (e.g. gmaven-plugin) and in [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) I haven't found any evidence it shouldn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the `exec-maven-plugin`. When configuration is defined for the execution any external configuration is ignored.

Comment: I get the following error with maven-exec-plugin: 'profiles.profile[my-profile].plugins.plugin.[org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin].executions.execution.id' must be unique but found duplicate execution with id ID1
So apparently, multiple executions must have different ids.

Answer (score 1):

Use properties that are set like this somewhere before they are used:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <myConfig>foo</myConfig>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Then use it like this

```
<execution>
    <id>ID1</id>
    <configuration>
        <myConfig>${myConfig}</myConfig>
         ...
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>ID2</id>
    <configuration>
        <myConfig>${myConfig}</myConfig>
         ...
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to be honest, I actually already do this exact behaviour with the <properties> tag. I'm instead looking for a way to share the <configuration> tag between multiple executions.

Comment: Though it seems reasonable that would be allowed, I know of no way to do that.